# entity framework 7 связь один-ко-многим

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь сделать ToDo List на Asp.net 5.
Есть две модели со связью один-ко-многим.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tdl_api.Models
{
    public class Reminder
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Create_date { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }

        public bool Status { get; set; }

        public long? TypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace tdl_api.Models
{
    public class Type
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Reminder> Reminders { get; set; }

        public Type()
        {
            Reminders = new HashSet<Reminder>();
        }
    }
}
```

Так же контекст данных

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace tdl_api.Models
{
    public class Contex: DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Reminder> reminders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Type> types { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Reminder>(e =>
            {
                e.HasOne(r => r.Type).WithMany(t => t.Reminders);
            });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

В репозитории получаю так:

```
List<Reminder> data = await _db.reminders.ToListAsync();
```

Но в объектах Reminder, все Type равны null (не подтягиваются). Что упустил?  Делал примерно как [тут.](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html)

Comment: Какой подход использовали: BaseFirst или ModelFirst?

Comment: Я думаю CodeFirst, ef7 вроде исключительно его поддерживает? Ну я написал классы (модели) и сделал миграцию

Comment: А саму базу не смотрели? Мне кажется, тут не хватает данных, чтобы понять что происходит.

Comment: а если сделать `Include()` т.е. явно подгрузить необходимые сущности? P.S.: Entity Framework 7 еще не щупал, но в 6 это работает так

Comment: Если использовать Include() сервер кидает ошибику 502.3

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте задать явно связи.

```
e.HasOne(r => r.Type).WithMany(t => t.Reminders)
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.TypeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Если каскадное удаление необходимо, то вместо false ставим true